# Meaning of "without replacement" in a specific exercise

Tags: probability

This is my question:

> Suppose you have $20$ marbles, each marked with a number from $1$ to $20$.  Two marbles are drawn without replacement.

Compute

a.  P(both marbles have numbers less than 12)

b.  P(the smallest number is greater than 4)

c.  P(one number is 8)

Does this mean the balls were taken out simultaneously or one after the other? I am confused. And what will be the answer?

Comment: Without replacement means the balls are not returned after they are drawn.

Comment: @Kaynex so were they taken out simultaneously or one after another? If they were taken out simultaneously, the total number of balls would be same but if they were taken out one after another, the number of balls in the bag would decrease, right?

Comment: @user494607 Without replacement means that the ball was not placed back into the bag. This means that the number of balls in the bag decreases. So you could say that they were taken "one after another".

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Be sure to add context - motivation, source, background, attempt - whenever you are asking a question. Make sure that when you are asking, you don't pretend to be helped without helping the community. Refer to the following link: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Just the odds the first marble you draw is less than 12, times the second being less than twelve $\frac{11}{20} \times \frac{10}{19}$

b) Similar to above, odds you draw a marble larger than 4, and then another one larger than 4 $\frac{16}{20} \times \frac{15}{19}$

c) Its the complement of the odds of not drawing the number 8, $ 1 - (\frac{19}{20} \times \frac{18}{19})$

Comment: This gives an answer to the OP's homework exercise, but doesn't directly answer the titular question here: namely what "without replacement" means.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing two marbles *with replacement* means that you draw a marble, put it back in the bag, then draw another marble. Thus it's possible to draw the same marble twice.

Drawing two marbles *without replacement* means you don't put the first marble back in the bag. Thus you cannot draw the same marble twice.